# Jquery mouseover with text and an image

Tags: jquery, html

so basically I'm using jquery to fade an image and make text appear when the users mouse hovers over a pictures. Here's my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#bd-text").hide();
});

$(function () {

    $("img").mouseover(function() {
        $(this).css('border', "solid 1px #2980b9"); 
        $(this).css('filter', "blur(3px)");
        $("#bd-text").show();
});

$("img").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css('border', "none"); 
    $(this).css('filter', "blur(0px)");
    $("#bd-text").hide();
});

});
</script>   
</head>

<body>
<div id="all">

<p style="text-align:center"><img id="borderlands" src="borderlands2.jpg"></p>
<p style="text-align:center"><img id="unknown" src="dev.png"></p>

<p id="bd-text">text that fades in</p>
<p id="dv-text">text that fades in</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem I have is that when the text appears, it will often appear on the user's mouse, and because the mouse is now over the text, the image is no longer faded. So what I want to know is if there is any way to make the text be ignored, so that the image will stay faded even if the user's mouse is over the text.

Thanks.

Comment: HI, welcome to SO, please tidy your code and make it _compilable_. Also, could you add your HTML to make the example more clear?

Comment: And please add the CSS code :)

Comment: Does adding a CSS `pointer-events: none;` solve this?

Comment: Note: `$( document ).ready(function() {` is equal to `$(function() {`.This second one is just the shorthand

Comment: @Tico yes it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS property **pointer-events** allows authors to control under what circumstances (if any) a particular graphic element can become the target of mouse events.Just add this property to the style rules for `#bd-text{}` and set the value to `none`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title title="test"></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #bd-text {
            position: absolute;
            color: #fff;
            top: 33%;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 20px;
            pointer-events: none;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {

            $("#bd-text").hide();

            $("img").mouseover(function () {
                $(this).css('border', "solid 1px #2980b9");
                $(this).css('filter', "blur(5px)");
                $("#bd-text").show();
            });

            $("img").mouseleave(function () {
                $(this).css('border', "none");
                $(this).css('filter', "blur(0px)");
                $("#bd-text").hide();
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="all">
        <p style="text-align:center"><img id="borderlands" src="/Images/image1.jpg"></p>
        <p style="text-align:center"><img id="unknown" src="Images/image2.jpg"></p>
        <p id="bd-text">text that fades in</p>
        <p id="dv-text">text that fades in</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```